# How to get a solution of this inequality?

Tags: inequalities

I used `f=((x1+x2+x3)y1+(x2+x3+x4)y2+(x3+x4+x1)y3+(x4+x1+x2)y4)^3/(108(x1 x2 x3+x2 x3 x4+x3 x4 x1+x4 x1 x2)(y1 y2 y3+y2 y3 y4+y3 y4 y1+y4 y1 y2)); NMinimize[{f,x1>0,x2>0,x3>0,x4>0,y1>0,y2>0,y4>0,y3>0},{x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y4,y3}]` and got the The minimum value of $f$ is $1$. Therefore, there exist a set of $x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4>0$ such that $1<f<\dfrac{10001}{10000}$，now I want to get a solution. I tried to use `FindInstance[{1<f<10001/10000,x1>0,x2>0,x3>0,x4>0,y1>0,y2>0,y4>0,y3>0},{x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y4,y3}]` but I've been waiting for a long time without results. Is there any other method to find a solution of $1<f<\dfrac{10001}{10000}$?

Comment: You could try something like `NMinimize[{1, 1 < f < 10001/10000, x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, 
  y1 > 0, y2 > 0, y4 > 0, y3 > 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3}]` It looks like there is only a solution `f==1` ...

Answer (score 2):

- We can use equation instead of inequality.

```
f = ((x1 + x2 + x3) y1 + (x2 + x3 + x4) y2 + (x3 + x4 + x1) y3 + (x4 +
          x1 + x2) y4)^3/(108 (x1 x2 x3 + x2 x3 x4 + x3 x4 x1 + 
       x4 x1 x2) (y1 y2 y3 + y2 y3 y4 + y3 y4 y1 + y4 y1 y2));

FindInstance[{f == 1 + 1/100000, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3} > 
   0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3}]
FindInstance[{f == 1 + 1/100000, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3} > 
   1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The function range of `f` is `f>=1` since we can set `x1 == x2 == x3 == x4 == y1 == y2 == y3` and get a two variables function `g` and find its functioin range.

```
g = Simplify[((x1 + x2 + x3) y1 + (x2 + x3 + x4) y2 + (x3 + x4 + 
         x1) y3 + (x4 + x1 + x2) y4)^3/(108 (x1 x2 x3 + x2 x3 x4 + 
       x3 x4 x1 + x4 x1 x2) (y1 y2 y3 + y2 y3 y4 + y3 y4 y1 + 
       y4 y1 y2)), {x1 == x2 == x3 == x4 == y1 == y2 == y3}]
FunctionRange[{g, y3 > 0, y4 > 0}, {y3, y4}, z]
(* z>=1 *)
```

Comment: @lapcal I have complete solve your original problem. If you have a new question,you should post  a new question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no unique solution.

`NMinimize` is able to solve only for the constarints

```
mini = NMinimize[{1, 1 < f <= 1 + 1/100000  , x1> 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, y1 > 0, y2 > 0, y4 > 0, y3 > 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2,    y4, y3}, Method ->"NelderMead"]

(*{1., {x1 -> 1.3162, x2 -> 1.3162, x3 -> 1.3162,x4 -> 1.3221, 
y1 -> 1.31598, y2 -> 1.31713, y4 -> 1.31713, y3 -> 1.31713}}*)
```

Alternatively one could look for a solution with nearly equal parameters  `x1~x2,x2~x3,...`

```
mini = NMinimize[{(x1 - x2)^2 + (x2 - x3)^2 + (x3- x4)^2 + (y1 -y2)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 + (y3 - y4)^2, 
1 < f <= 1+ 1/100000  ,x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, y1 > 0, y2 > 0,y4> 0, y3 > 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y4, y3}, Method-> "NelderMead"]

(*{5.69018*10^-17, {x1 -> 0.998308, x2 ->0.998308, x3 -> 0.998308,x4 -> 0.998308, 
y1 -> 1.00105, y2 -> 1.00105, y4 ->1.00105, y3 -> 1.00105}}*)
```